# How to keep dropdown input values after validation fails with spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot and thymeleaf for a project.I have a form that consists of text fields, dropdown menus and a file input field. The dropdowns are populated from models I send in the getControler for the view. When I added validation for the fields that returns the user to the same page and shows the error messages, all the values from the dropdowns are gone and the file is also not there. How can I keep the dropdowns populated after the validation fails.

Controllers:

```
@GetMapping("/makeLog")
public String makeLog(Model model) {
    if (!securityService.isAuthenticated()) {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    model.addAttribute("waters", waterService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("logForm", new FishJournal());
    model.addAttribute("baits", baitService.findAll());
    return "makeLog";
}

@PostMapping("/makeLog")
public String makeLog(@ModelAttribute("logForm") FishJournal logForm,  
        @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile, BindingResult bindingResult)throws IOException { {
            
             journalValidator.validate(logForm, bindingResult);
             if(!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
                 pictureValidator.validate(multipartFile, bindingResult);
             }
             
                if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                      return "makeLog";
                }   
                
                
            
                Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                   String username;
                  
                   
                   if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
                        username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
                       } else {
                        username = principal.toString();
                       }
                   User currentUser=userService.findByUsername(username);
   
   
   
   logForm.setPath(pictureService.getFishPicUploadPath(multipartFile));
   
   
   
   logForm.setDate(new Date());
   logForm.setUsers(currentUser);
   journalService.save(logForm);
   

    return "redirect:/";
}


}
```

Part of the view named makeLog showing one of my dropdowns:

```
 <form method="POST" class="fish-log" th:object="${logForm}" th:action="@{/makeLog}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your Fishing Log</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select th:field="*{waters}" class="form-control" id="water">
            <option value=""selected hidden>Изберете водоем...</option>
        <option th:each="water : ${waters}"
                th:value="${water.id}"
                th:text="${water.name}">
        </option>
    </select>
     <span class="has-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('waters')}" th:errors="*{waters}"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: This kind of problem is one of the many reasons that many developers have moved to client-side "SPAs", single page applications, where there is no such "refresh" required, so state is not lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the model attributes again if there is a validation error. Update your `@PostMapping` method like this;

```
@PostMapping("/makeLog")
public String makeLog(@ModelAttribute("logForm") FishJournal logForm,  
        @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile, BindingResult bindingResult)throws IOException { {
            
             journalValidator.validate(logForm, bindingResult);
             if(!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
                 pictureValidator.validate(multipartFile, bindingResult);
             }
             
                if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                      model.addAttribute("waters", waterService.findAll());
                      model.addAttribute("baits", baitService.findAll());
                      return "makeLog";
                }   
                
                
            
                Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                   String username;
                  
                   
                   if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
                        username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
                       } else {
                        username = principal.toString();
                       }
                   User currentUser=userService.findByUsername(username);
   
   
   
   logForm.setPath(pictureService.getFishPicUploadPath(multipartFile));
   
   
   
   logForm.setDate(new Date());
   logForm.setUsers(currentUser);
   journalService.save(logForm);
   

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Extra tips:

- You can use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to inject the current user into the method so you don't have to use the `SecurityContextHolder` yourself.
- The `BindingResult` variable should be directly after the `@ModelAttribute` and you should add `@Valid` to the `@ModelAttribute` as well.

Comment: that worked what exactly does @Valid anotation do ?

Comment: It reads the validation annotations that are on the class (on `FishJournal` in your case) and will populate the `BindingResult` parameter. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/ for example.

Comment: i am using a custom validator implementing the Validator interface which in the code is  pictureValidator.validate(multipartFile, bindingResult); isn't that doing the same job ?

Comment: Maybe. I just like to use the annotations based approach, but if the validator validates, then it should be all good :)

Comment: yeah, i think it does the same thing thank you for all the help man you are great!